# Equivalent query in sql server for INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am working on a page where we need to visually compare the schema of same table across the two database-one in sql server and other in mysql.I have to include indexes as well.

now mysql query shows info along with indexes -

```
select column_name,column_type,table_name,column_key 
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'tbl_ClientDN'
```

But for sql server the same query does not return indexes-

```
 select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'tbl_ClientDN'
```

so i need query to compbine the result of -

```
 sp_helpindex 'tbl_ClientDN'
```

how to get column_key showing indexes in mssql query.
any suggestion ?

Comment: Does RedGate SQL Compare work on mysql?  That's the tool we use to compare table schemas.

Comment: +1 to @BrianWhite's comment. http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stay away from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, especially for indexes, since things like filtered indexes and included columns are not part of the definition. I talk about this in more detail here:

- [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

You want to use `sys.indexes` and `sys.index_columns` for this. For example:

```
DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(512) = 'dbo.tbl_ClientDN';

SELECT
    [Index]  = i.name,
    [Column] = c.Name, 
    [Type]   = i.type_desc,
    PK = i.is_primary_key,
    [Unique] = i.is_unique,
    [Unique Constraint] = i.is_unique_constraint,
    [DESC] = ic.is_descending_key,
    [INCLUDE] = ic.is_included_column,
    [Filtered] = i.filter_definition -- only for SQL Server 2008+
FROM
    sys.indexes AS i 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns AS ic 
    ON i.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] 
    AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c
    ON ic.column_id = c.column_id
    AND ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE 
    i.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
ORDER BY [Index], ic.index_column_id;
```

If you want to do this for all tables at once, then simple changes:

```
SELECT
    [Table] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.[object_id]))
      + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id])),
    [Index]  = i.name,
    [Column] = c.Name, 
    [Type]   = i.type_desc,
    PK = i.is_primary_key,
    [Unique] = i.is_unique,
    [Unique Constraint] = i.is_unique_constraint,
    [DESC] = ic.is_descending_key,
    [INCLUDE] = ic.is_included_column,
    [Filtered] = i.filter_definition -- only for SQL Server 2008+
FROM
    sys.indexes AS i 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns AS ic 
    ON i.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] 
    AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c
    ON ic.column_id = c.column_id
    AND ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
ORDER BY [Table], [Index], ic.index_column_id;
```

More information available in the topics [sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) and [sys.index_columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-index-columns-transact-sql).

You also might want to take a look at Kimberley L. Tripp's [sp_helpindex2](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/Kimberly/post/Updates-%28fixes%29-to-sp_helpindex2.aspx).

---

**EDIT**

In general I agree with @BrianWhite's comment. If you are spending any effort on this at all, you should be using a tool for this instead of re-inventing the wheel and trying to write it yourself. Troubleshooting this one query you've probably already spent, in terms of time, the cost of a good tool. Please read this post:

- [The cost of reinventing the wheel](http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/)

Comment: thanks for updates Aaron.I wish i could use a nice tool like RedGate but unfortunately  we need to do it using our existing monitor UI(java project).highly appreciate your reply & suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are after `sp_help`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx

Simply entering

```
sp_help myTableName
```

should give you all the data you could want.

Comment: well.thanks Mathew .yeah,i get all info (lot more than i need)from sp_help but is it ok performance wise if UI calls sp_help for each table on production servers also?

Comment: I think sp_help in a loop against all the tables is overkill and gets you a lot more info than you need. I also don't know how you're going to consume those results. I updated my answer to include a single query that gets index data for all tables instead of a specified table as your question asks for.